# How can I stop Apache tomcat to log 404 errors in Application Insights? GET/* Error

Tags: angular, tomcat, azure-application-insights

I have deployed an angular application in a Tomcat app server in Azure App Service.
In order to enable fallback into index.html I included a web.xml file inside /WEB-INFO folder with this content:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>App</display-name>    
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Even though this solution works, I still see "GET/*" errors in **Application Insights** every time page refreshes.

[image]

Following Angular documentation, I have tried to include an .htaccess file in app service files with no luck. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

What am I missing?

Below are my App Service settings...

[image]

Comment: Note: Apache Tomcat is not Apache httpd, and Tomcat doesn't know what to do with a `.htaccess` file. And the folder that tomcat checks for a `web.xml` file is called `/WEB-INF` (within your web application)

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, Whatever the suggestions given by [Olaf Kock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13447/olaf-kock) are true there is nothing can be done my Tomcat with `.htaccess` as because Tom Cat is not Apache httpd.
- Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config) that refers installation of Tomcat Plus, add the application insights.
- And this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments#tomcat-8-windows) describes different ways of Installation of [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

We asked the Microsoft support team and we found out we shouldn't be deploying the Angular application into the app service but into other Azure service: **Static Web Apps**